# How do I force a jQuery click event to proceed any control click event on ASP.Net page

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I've found posts about making a click event with jQuery for a button, however I need a little more then that.

When any postback occurs on a page, I need to fire off a jQuery click event.  Based on a condition, I want to continue processing (including running the server-side event code after the jQuery code), or, perform a redirect.

I'm not quite sure how to go about this.

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to handle *every* postback, the simplest way to do it is to replace the `__doPostBack` function with your own wrapper, like this:

```
var originalDoPostBack = __doPostBack;
__doPostBack = function() { 
    //Run some code
    if(something)
        originalDoPostBack.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Thanks SLaks --

If I use your sample -- and my condition "something" is the test I need to determine to do a redirect...  And I leave that code as is and don't handle the 'else', will it automatically execute my server code, or do I need to return true(or something else)?

Comment: Handle the form's submit event and cancel it.  (Selectively)